# How to seperate nodes that have melted together in a Latex tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a beginner, making trees in Latex, but some of my nodes keep melting together. [image]

They are not supposed to be linked in anyway, but I cannot find out what I am doing wrong.

[image: This is my code, and the two nodes that melts together]

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. Please provide code what you try so far (copy it from your editor and store in question). Its image is not very helpful, it require to retype it from scratch, so please help people who will wiling to help you. Otherwise it seems that you have problems with poorly defined `sibling distances`.